# Determining the Coordinates of the point on the x-axis that are equidistant

Tags: vectors

So I've been doing my homework without any trouble so far and I came across this question that I did not understand how to do.

Given the points A(-2,1,3) and B(4,-1,3), determine the coordinates of the point on the x-axis that are equidistant from these two points.

My process:

I figured out that equidistant means at equal distances, so point would be half way between A and B. SO I figured out the vector AB = (6,2,0) and then I though to divide it in 2. However this is wrong.

The answer at the back of my text book is (1,0,0).

How would I go about finding the answer? Is my thought process wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can go about it.

We begin by determining the *plane* of all points $(x,y,z)$ equidistant from those two points. The segment from $A$ to $B$ will be orthogonal to the plane, so the plane will have the equation $6x-2y+d=0$ for some constant $d$. Moreover, the plane will bisect this segment, so the midpoint of $A$ and $B$ will lie in the plane. That is, $(1,0,3)$ will lie in the plane, so $6+d=0,$ and so $d=-6.$ Hence, the plane has equation $$6x-2y-6=0.$$ To find the $x$-coordinate of the point in this plane lying on the $x$-axis, we set $y=z=0,$ and solve for $x,$ to find that $x=1,$ so that $(1,0,0)$ is the point in question.

Comment: Where did you get the equation 6 + d = 0?

Comment: By substituting $x=1,y=0,z=3$ into the equation $6x-2y+d=0.$

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the equation is obtained by supstituting vector AB in the equation ax + by + cz + d = 0

Comment: Somewhat, though that's a bit imprecise. Since we know that $\vec{AB}=\langle4-(-2),-1-1,3-3\rangle=\langle6,-2,0\rangle$ is orthogonal to the plane, then we know that $a=6,b=-2,c=0$ works. (It would also be okay to have $a=6t,b=-2t,c=0t=0$ for any non-zero real $t,$ but that's a side note.)

Answer (score 0):

The above method works, but I find this one easier
You know |AP|=|BP| when
P(x,0,0)
A(-2,1,3)
B(4,-1,3)
Calculate AP and BP
AP(x+2,-1,-3)
BP(x-4,1,-3)
Then set the magnitudes equal and solve for x (the roots cancel out)
(x+2)^2+10=(x-4)^2+10
x=1
therefore 
P(1,0,0)